# Why fno-sanitize is not taken into account for a subproject CMAKE, disable sanitizer for a target

Tags: c++, cmake, address-sanitizer

I'm working on a CMake projects with several targets.

I'm activating ADDRESS SANITIZER by CMake (`ccmake .` and put `ADDRESS_SANITIZER=ON`). It is activated correctly, although I would like to inactivate it on one of the target. To do this, I added `-fno-sanitize=all` to the compiler flags of the target but it is not taken into account.

Is there a way to inactivate the sanitizer for a certain target? The target in question does not depend on any library or any other target of the project. It only depends on LLVM libraries installed on the machine.

The subproject has its own `CMakeList.txt` and added as a subproject to the main one.

`-fno-sanitize=all` is set by `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-sanitize=all"`

Comment: `ADDRESS_SANITIZER=ON` seems to be specific to your project so we can't know what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-sanitize=all` I've used `target_compile_options(target -fno-sanitize=all)` which solved the problem.